# instagram api comments fetch

Tags: api, instagram

Is there a way to determine when a new comment is posted without refetching all data? Does instagram return the results set in chronological order and can a user update a comment and does this alter the created date time? Just starting to look at the api and documentation does not clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Get a full list of comments on a media object. Go here `http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/#get_media_comments`